# Split out column in SSIS into multiple columns that groups the data together

Tags: sql, ssis

I've got a table that looks something like the below. For simplicities sake i'm just keeping the numbers basic.

| Area | Days | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Area 1 | 35 | 1000 |
| Area 2 | 35 | 1000 |
| Area 3 | 35 | 1000 |
| Area 1 | 60 | 4000 |
| Area 2 | 60 | 4000 |
| Area 3 | 60 | 4000 |

I'm trying to use SSIS to split out the days across 2 different columns.

| Area | 35D | 60D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Area 1 | 1000 | 4000 |
| Area 2 | 1000 | 4000 |
| Area 3 | 1000 | 4000 |

From what I've seen, derived columns seem to be the way forward but I can't quite figure out how to get the values in, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like as task for [Pivot Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/pivot-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: An alternative could be to use a database view to pivot your data as a source for your Dataflow. I found SSIS transformations like "Pivot" or "Slowly changing dimension" not performing too well in comparison to their native SQL equivalent.